# Add where condition based on record exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add where condition based on if record exists in the table or not
for example

```
if record exists in table A then 
select * from table B where B='12' 

otherwise 
select * from table B.
```

I am creating a view with the above queries.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can write this as:

```
select *
from B
where B = '12' or
      exists (<record in A>)
```

I'm not sure how the existence condition is expressed.  For any record, it would be:

```
select *
from B
where B = '12' or
      exists (select 1 from A)
```

Comment: The optimizer is clever enough to not evaluate every `B = '12'` if the `exists` already returned `true`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists(select * from B where B = '12')
begin
    select * from B where B = '12'
end
else
begin 
    select * from B 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
select * from b where (b = 12 and exists (select 1 from a where a = record)) or b = b
```

Its give you; if record in table a get b=12 value else get b values with no condition.

Comment: Hi if i have one more condition i mean select * from table b where b.id=1 and (b.sal =12) i want to add this b.sal condition only when there is data in (select 1 from table a)

Comment: I am understand, you can try this code block;

select *
  from b
 where b.id = 1
   and ((b.sal = 12 and exists (select 1
                                  from a)) or b.sal = b.sal)

Comment: I hope you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if exists(select * from A)
begin
select * from B where B = '12'
end
else
begin 
select * from B 
end
```

Comment: i am creating a view with the above queries. so is it possible to write if condition please help